# Global Facebook login session accessible for all activities

Tags: java, android, facebook, class, android-activity

**Hello everyone!**

Im currently developing an Android Application for mobiles using the official Facebook SDK. The first screen on my application is the LoginActivity. That activity is bringing up an Facebook login dialog, were the user can enter his facebook username and password and then press the login button. I think you know which dialog im talking about, i bet you have seen it somewhere.

When the user are logging to Facebook using that dialog, theres a Facebook session which are set to true, exactly as it should be. **BUT**, I found out that this session is only true if you are in the LoginActivity. If the user makes an successfull login to Facebook the user are moved to another Activity by this code:

```
private class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(LoginActivity.this,   LocationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

And when the user are moved to the new activity in this case *LocationActivity*,
the session is still true but only for the LoginActivity. I want the session to be global and be true for the whole application and all activities as soon as the user are logging in.

Here is some code from LoginActivity, i hope this will make your guys to understand it all better, i bet if i post the whole activity no one would read it.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

public static final String APP_ID = "123123123123123";
public static final String TAG = "FACEBOOK CONNECT";
private Facebook mFacebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
private static final String[] PERMS = new String[] { "user_events" };
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
}
```

...

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case FacebookCon.LOGIN:
        if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
            AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(
                    mFacebook);
            asyncRunner.logout(this, new LogoutRequestListener());
        } else {
            mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
        }
        break;
```

...

```
private class LogoutRequestListener implements RequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {

        // Dispatch on its own thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            }
        });
    }
```

A friend told me that i should make a "ApplicationController", i did not really understand what that were but he said that class should extend the whole application and all the variabels in the ApplicationController would be global for the whole application, and that's what i would like to do with the loginsession so it won't get lose when changing activities. But i don't know how to make this changes in my Application so i would like to have some help with this.

Comment: Developer questions are off-topic here; migrating to [SO].

Comment: Im so sorry, i though android.stackexchange.com was for Android Developers.